# Is it possible to turn off NAT on some cheap wireless router?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt, nat

http://amzn.com/B001FWYGJS

I have several TP-Link and other brands' wireless router like that in above amazon link.

They seem in common to default to not allow user to turn off NAT when I want to expose the IP addresses in subnet provided by the router.

Is what I think right? Or maybe I missed something?

I heard that dd-wrt can do it...

Is there some cheap model that default to provide this configuartion?

Comment: The moment you install DDWRT, yeah - otherwise google to see if the router has 'access point mode'

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately many Wi-Fi home gateways that don't let you disable NAT. To use those as simple APs (access points; something that just bridges between wireless clients and a wired Ethernet), what you have to do is turn off their DHCP server (or set its DHCP IP address lease pool to a zero-length range), and then plug the LAN port (not the WAN port) into your home LAN.